# RBAC in Jenkins: How to create custom permission for only users and groups management

Tags: jenkins, permissions, rbac

I installed Role-based authorization strategy plugin in Jenkins LTS. Please can you give me feedback about "RBAC: How to create custom permission for only users and groups management" I see the "Credentials section" (inside Manage Roles) has the following permissions: Create /Delete /ManageDomains/Update /View. So, is possible to create similar permissions for only users and groups management?

Additionally, can you confirm if in Jenkins LTS or in CloudBees Jenkins Disstribution is possible to create groups ? Or in which versions can I do that?

Best Regards!